# onIncrement math question involving state

Tags: reactjs, math, state

I am trying to increment the quantity of a product using an onClick called onIncrement. The function is as follows:

```
  const onIncrement = () => {
    setState({ ...state, quantity: (state.quantity) + 1 });
    props.productList(props.productData.price*(state.quantity + 1))
  };
```

I would like the button to simply add +1 to the product each time the button is clicked. Unfortunately, this function is doubling the quantity each time I click the button. Is there an easy way to fix this? I tried to do:

```
  const onIncrement = () => {
    setState({ ...state, quantity: (state.quantity)/(state.quantity) + 1 });
    props.productList(props.productData.price*(state.quantity + 1))
  };
```

To negate the effect of the state.quantity and just add one, but it's not working. Am I missing something in the formula? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `setState` is asynchronous the state change will not get triggered as soon as the function gets called. It'll get updated in the background. So, it's always recommended to use the functional way of updating the state using `setState` i.e., like below

```
 const onIncrement = () => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, quantity: (state.quantity) + 1 }));
 };
```

This way always when you are trying to use previous state in order to update, you'll get the updated state. And also `setState` also accepts a second parameter which is a `callback`. **This callback will be triggered once the state gets updated** so that the updated state will be available for use. For more info you can refer [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

So in your case if you wish to calculate the price of the product based on the updated quantity after the state update then you can do that in the `callback` of `setState` as discussed above

```
const onIncrement = () => {
   setState((state) => ({ ...state, quantity: (state.quantity) + 1 }), () => {
      props.productList(props.productData.price*(state.quantity + 1))
   });
}
```

In fact your scenario this can be done in a simpler way as well like below

```
const onIncrement = () => {
    const updatedQuantity = state.quantity + 1
    setState(() => ({ ...state, quantity: updatedQuantity }));
    props.productList(props.productData.price*(updatedQuantity))
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Works like a charm

Comment: Happy to have helped you. Please accept the answer, Thank you :)